# HTML drop down form adding options in JS: does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a simple HTML drop down form that functions as a simple navigation menu. The menu items that are loaded into the form don't appear in Firefox. I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Here is the form's HTML:

```
<form id="list">
    <select name="navigation">
        <option value="index.html">Projects</option>
        <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is the JS (located in another file):

```
var navigation = [
    {"title": "1", url: "1.html"},
    {"title": "2", url: "2.html"},
    {"title": "3", url: "3.html"},
];

var select = document.getElementById("list").navigation;

for (var i=0, option; i<navigation.length; i++) {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = navigation[i].url;
    option.innerText = navigation[i].title;
    select.appendChild(option);
}

select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    window.location.href = select.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use innerHTML instead of innerText

Answer (score 0):

You should use `textContent` property.